# Can I use two external monitors from single display port on Dell XPS-13 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Is it possible to use two external monitors on my Dell XPS-13? It has a single miniDP. I see a couple of `disconnected` options in the output of `xrandr`, which is below. Thanks.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is superuser output using `lshw -numeric -C display`

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

My XPS-13 is a few years old; it has 3 ports: one USB3 port, one USB3 w/powershare,and a miniDP

The adapter I am using is:
StarTech MDP2VGDVHD Mini DisplayPort Adapter - 3-in-1 - 1080p - Monitor Adapter - Mini DP to HDMI / VGA / DVI Adapter Hub

Answer (score 0):

Let's first walk through the list of outputs

- `eDP1` this stands for [embedded Display Port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174695/why-is-laptop-screen-called-edp1?newreg=8e036ea44c184de3b0987e186528bc8a) and means your internal laptop screen.
- `DP1` this is the miniDP you are speaking of
- `HDMI1` I guess this is actually a USB 3.1 or Thunderbolt 3 port. I have not seen those in action.
- `VIRTUAL1` This could be [a lot of things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209947/xrandr-where-does-virtual1-output-come-from), but nothing you can use directly.

I see two ways to connect two monitors

1. Connect one over a USB 3.1 hdmi converter and the other one over miniDP
2. [daisy-chain](https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/) your monitors over display port (if they support it) (see e.g. this [tutorial by dell](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln293813/how-to-configure-two-external-monitors-with-displayport-12-multi-stream-support-to-work-with-the-precision-m4800?lang=en])

---

please shed some more light into how everything is connected as of now, so I can improve the answer (especially with regards to the `HDMI1` thing)

Comment: I have an adapter connected to the mDP that has three ports. I have one monitor connected via the hdmi port on the adapter, and another connected to the vga port. Only the hdmi monitor works; I tried turning off the native display to see if the other monitor would show up, and although I can choose that option via the button, the embedded display does not turn off.  Thanks for the link for the daisy-chain hookup; I will check that out. The only ports on my machine are two USB3 ports and the mini display port

Comment: are you sure you have a mDP at all? The [Dell Specs](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/xps-13-laptop/spd/xps-13-9360-laptop) just lists thunderbolt. What kind of adapter are you using? you Should add that information to your original question

Comment: According to my Dell service tag info, my machine has the following external ports and connectors
USB •  One USB 3.0 port
       •  One USB 3.0 port with PowerShare
Audio/video •  One Mini DisplayPort
                       •  One headphone / microphone combo (headset) port  The adapter is a Startech.com adapter

Answer (score 0):

If your model of XPS-13 supports DisplayPort 1.2+ then yes you can use multiple displays over the single mini DisplayPort connection, by using DisplayPort 1.2+ cables, and monitors that support daisy-chaining the DisplayPort 1.2+ connection.

If your laptop only supports DisplayPort less than 1.2, then no, you cannot do this. The adapter you list in your question can only convert to one single display type. You can't use it to gain multi-monitor display.